# Wireless connection among two or more laptops without internet

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, screen-sharing, telecommunication

My question is that I want my two devices (laptops) to screenshare like whatever is shown on one laptop should be displayed on other like AnyDesk/TeamViewer.

However I want this type of communication to be done **without internet** over **1km distance** between two devices.

Is there any possible way?

Comment: Without internet? How?

Comment: Are you asking about apps that work without Internet access or about the physical means of connecting the computers?

Comment: Sure, you just need a network (not internet) connection - which could be wire, fiber or long range radio/microwave link and an app that can do screen sharing without internet access for example remote desktop.

Comment: Yes this is possible. There are two problems you need to solve: The distance of the communication and the method of remote viewing. Both are very solvable. There are hardware solutions that can send LAN traffic across long distances, and there are remove viewer tools that operate entirely on a LAN and do not require any internet host. We do not recommend products though. I recommend you look at each of these separately and solve them, and as you come across specific problems you cannot solve, share those here.

Comment: @u1686_grawity it could be any app or any hardware device.

Comment: @music2myear Thankyou for this informative reply , I will look into this scenario now. However I was trying to search transmitter and receiver with video and data links e.g VIULINX PRO which are majorly used for drone applications. What do you say such hardware device will be suitable for my problem ? Secondly if possible do share the hardware solutions for LAN traffics.

Comment: Please read our comments carefully and thoroughly. In my comment I specified that we do not recommend products. In the guides and suggestions you were presented with when you began posting this question you would have been advised to read the rules in the Help section, once of which clearly states that product recommendation requests are not allowed on this site.

Comment: @music2myear oh okay ,I apologize basically I have just joined this site.

Comment: You did not offend me, but I appreciate your intent. This site has some specific rules and reasons for those rules. Great efforts are spent trying to ensure that people coming and asking questions are shown those rules. I have personally found this site very valuable, and I had to learn the rules too, and knowing those rules made the site even more useful to me.

Comment: @music2myear Thankyou for guiding me :)